# Learn to recognize whether an image of a handwritten digit and a recording refer to the same or different number

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've two datasets to compare, 1) handwritten digits 0-9 as a 784-dimensional vector, 28x28 pixel grayscale image, and 2) recordings of a spoken name of a digit in Arabic ("zero", "one", etc.) given as an array of pre-extracted audio features MFCC. Each recording has a variable length with an array of shape (N, 13), N = number of frames, and 13 = the number of MFCC features.

To train I've a few datasets consisting of:

- written_train.npy: array with 45,000 rows and 784 columns
- written_test.npy: array with 15,000 rows and 784 columns
- spoken_train.npy: array with 45,000 rows. Each row is an object of
  shape (N, 13)
- spoken_test.npy: array with 15,000 rows. Each row is an object of shape
  (N, 13)
- match_train.npy: array with 45,000 boolean values (False or True)

In the array from match_train there is a value at index j that specifies whether the image at row j from written_train and the audio at row j from spoken_train refer to the same number.

The goal is to have get a lowest error rate accuracy as possible.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.  This will get better response in one of the broader sites in machine learning.